# Differentiation of $l^p(\mathbb{N})$ norm

Tags: real-analysis, normed-spaces, banach-spaces, frechet-derivative

I was asked a problem, to show that $x\mapsto \Vert x\Vert_{l^p}^p=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \vert x_k\vert^p$ is differentiable at any point $x\in l^p(\mathbb{N})$ when $p\in]1,\infty[$ and twice differentiable when $p\in[2,\infty[$.

Where are talking Fréchet differentiability here ($l^p(\mathbb{N})$ being a Banach space). My guess is that it would mimic the way it works on $\mathbb{R}^n$ but I cannot seem to figure out how to properly write that out in this infinite dimension context.

Is writing

$$
\Vert x+h\Vert_{l^p(\mathbb{N})}^p-\Vert x\Vert_{l^p(\mathbb{N})}^p
$$
for $h=(h_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\in l^p(\mathbb{N})$ even relevant in the first place to answer the question ?

Thank you for your help !

Comment: It helps to think of directional derivatives along the $e_j$ first. This will give you a candidate for the total differential $A_x$ and then you need to show that $$ \Vert x+ h\Vert_p^p -\Vert x\Vert_p^p -A_x(h) = o(\Vert h\Vert_p).$$ When you also can show that $A_x$ is continuous, then we have $(D \Vert \cdot \Vert_p^p)(x)[h] = A_x(h)$.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven So I would guess that
$$ A_x(h)=p\sum_{j\in \mathbb{N}} \vert x_j\vert^{p-1} sgn(x_j)h_j$$
It is defined thanks to Holder inequality, it is also linear in $h$.
We have
$$\Vert x+h\Vert_p^p-\Vert x\Vert_p^p-A_x(h)=\sum_{j\in\mathbb{N}}\vert x_j+h_j\vert^p-\vert x_j\vert^p-p\vert x_j\vert^{p-1}sgn(x_j)h_j$$

But how wan I compare asymptotically with $\Vert h\Vert_p$ ?

Comment: I would try something like this: Set $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, \ f(x) = \vert x \vert^p$. Then we can write
$$ \Vert x + h \Vert_p^p - \Vert x \Vert_p^p - A_x(h) = \sum_{j\in \mathbb{N}} (f(x_j + h_j) - f(x_j) - f'(x_j)h_j) $$
Using the mean value theorem we know that there exists $\xi_j$ between $x_j$ and $x_j+h_j$ such that
$$ \Vert x + h \Vert_p^p - \Vert x \Vert_p^p - A_x(h) = \sum_{j\in \mathbb{N}} (f'(\xi_j)  - f'(x_j))\cdot h_j. $$

Comment: And thus
$$ \vert \Vert x + h \Vert_p^p - \Vert x \Vert_p^p - A_x(h) \vert \leq p\sum_{j\in \mathbb{N}} \vert \vert x_j + h_j \vert^{p-1}  - \vert x_j \vert^{p-1} \vert \cdot \vert h_j \vert. $$
Then we can try to use Hölder's inequality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use my comments and the fact that for $p\in (1,2]$ the function $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, x\mapsto \vert x \vert^{p-1}$ is $(p-1)$-Hölder continuous (with constant equal to $1$). To obtain
$$ \vert \Vert x+h \Vert_p^p - \Vert x \Vert_p^p - A_x(h) \vert \leq p \Vert h \Vert_p^p.$$
Hence, we get
$$ \frac{\vert \Vert x+h \Vert_p^p - \Vert x \Vert_p^p - A_x(h) \vert}{\Vert h \Vert_p} \leq p \Vert h \Vert_p^{p-1} \rightarrow 0 $$
for $\Vert h \Vert_p \rightarrow 0$.

For $p\in (2,\infty)$ we can use the mean value theorem once more and get $\eta_j$ between $x_j$ and $\xi_j$ such that 
$$ \Vert x+h \Vert_p^p - \Vert x \Vert_p^p - A_x(h) = \sum_{j\in \mathbb{N}} f''(\eta_j)(\xi_j - x_j) \cdot h_j. $$
Thus, we get
$$ \vert \Vert x+h \Vert_p^p - \Vert x \Vert_p^p - A_x(h) \vert \leq \sum_{j\in \mathbb{N}} \vert f''(\eta_j) \vert \cdot \vert h_j \vert^2. $$
Therefore,
$$ \vert \Vert x+h \Vert_p^p - \Vert x \Vert_p^p - A_x(h) \vert \leq p(p-1)\sum_{j\in \mathbb{N}} (\vert x_j \vert + \vert h_j \vert)^{p-2}\cdot \vert h_j \vert^2. $$
Hölder gives us
$$ \vert \Vert x+h \Vert_p^p - \Vert x \Vert_p^p - A_x(h) \vert \leq p(p-1)\Vert (\vert x_j \vert + \vert h_j \vert)_{j\in \mathbb{N}}\Vert_p^{p-2} \cdot \Vert h \Vert_p^2. $$
For $\Vert h \Vert_p \leq \Vert x \Vert_p$ we get
$$ \vert \Vert x+h \Vert_p^p - \Vert x \Vert_p^p - A_x(h) \vert \leq p(p-1)(\Vert x \Vert_p + \Vert h \Vert_p)^{p-2} \cdot \Vert h \Vert_p^2
\leq p(p-1)2^{p-2} \Vert x \Vert_p^{p-2} \cdot \Vert h \Vert_p^2. $$

Comment: Really nice proof ! Just a note, it is $g: x\mapsto \vert x\vert^{p-1}$ which is $p-1$-Hölder continuous, not $f$ itself. And I do not find a constant equal to $2$ but $1$, as if $x\geqslant y\geqslant 0$, $$x^a-y^a\leqslant (x-y)^a$$ for $a\in (0,1]$.

Comment: Indeed, I was sloppy, sorry for that. Let me correct it.

Comment: In your last steps, how do you know that 
$$\Vert (\vert x_j\vert+\vert h_j\vert)_{j\in\mathbb{N}}\Vert_p$$
actually exists ? You seem to be using $\vert a+b\vert^{p}\leqslant\vert a\vert^{p}+\vert b\vert^{p}$ but this only holds for $p\in[0,1]$.

Comment: Shouldn't we require $\vert h_j\vert\leqslant\vert x_j\vert$ for all $j$ instead of $\Vert h\Vert_p\leqslant\Vert x\Vert_p$ ?
And is is possible to do so ?

Comment: No, I just use the triangular inequality to get $$ \Vert (\vert x_j\vert + \vert h_j\vert )_{j\in\mathbb{N}} \Vert_p \leq  \Vert (\vert x_j\vert)_{j\in \mathbb{N}} \Vert_p + \Vert (\vert h_j \vert)_{j\in\mathbb{N}} \Vert_p =\Vert x\Vert_p + \Vert h\Vert_p.$$ Requiring $\vert h_j\vert \leq \vert x_j\vert$ is not an option as many of the $x_j$ could vanish and we are only allowed to control $\Vert h\Vert_p$.

Comment: Completely right, thanks for the follow up!

Comment: You're welcome :)